# Can a trusted web activity take part of the screen while the remaining screen shows the activity in background

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

I have a use case where I want to open a web page in TWA and come back to my app.  But, I want to show the page in a TWA and occupy just the bottom part of the screen, while my remaining app is shown in the rest of the screen.  Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Please refer to 5th point [in this Google's TWA docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa).

*`Transitions between web and native content are between activities. Each activity (i.e. screen) of your app is either completely provided by the web, or by an Android activity`*

Comment: I understand that the TWA will be in a separate activity, but,  want that activity to not take the whole screen. I want it to be transluscent, like the `AccountPicker` activity

Comment: The TWA Activity itself can't be transparent. It's possible to open a transparent Activity on top of it. As curiosity, what's the use-case?

Comment: In a login flow, we want to login through the TWA and get a token back on to the native app to login the user.  This is in order to take advantage of a previous chrome login of the user.